# How to include external TXT and XML resources to Runnable Jar export in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar, executable-jar

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk8Sr.png) are the 2 files I need to make my program work (***customers.txt*** & ***log4j2.xml***). They are placed directly in the project folder. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWGFV.png) is the execution of the Jar file in the command prompt. As you can see, it cannot find either ***customers.txt*** or ***log4j2.xml***. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfP6H.png) was what happened when I exported my program into a Runnable Jar file. I don't know what this error means.

Running the program in Eclipse works fine, but error occurs when exported as Jar file. What is the fix? Thank you very much.

In case it matters, Basically what my program does is: 
1. Read the ***customer.txt*** file using `BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));`
2. Do some stuff 
3. Output a new .txt file using `PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));`
4. Log some stuff using the ***log4j2.xml*** configuration file.
5. Output a log file.

Comment: Put the files that should be packed into the JAR into the source folder. But files in a JAR cannot be read as `File`s, e.g. instead of `new FileReader(inputFile)` you have to use `new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(inputFileName)`.